# unordered_map static assertion failed

Tags: c++, stl, static, assertion

I can't declare an unordered_map because of a static assertion failed error. First of, what is a static assertion? I searched for answers but the documentation has been incomprehensible to me. Here's the declaration:

```
std::unordered_map<Point3D<int>, int> tree;
```

And here's the struct Point3D

```
template <class T>
struct Point3D
{
public:
    T x, y, z;

    Point3D(T _x, T _y, T _z) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z)
    {
    }
};
```

What could or should I do to make it work?

Thank you! :)

Comment: A static assert is something that is checked at compile time, rather than runtime like normal asserts

Comment: And what does the error message say? Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using MinGW (gcc, g++) with Code::Blocks. The error says it's not implemented. I don't have my laptop right so I'll check again the message later.

Comment: c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\functional_hash.h|60|error: static assertion failed: std::hash is not specialized for this type|

Answer (score 1):

This compiles Ok for me under Visual Studio 2010:

```
#include <unordered_map>
template <class T>
struct Point3D
{
public:
    T x, y, z;

    Point3D(T _x, T _y, T _z) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z)
    {
    }
};
std::unordered_map<Point3D<int>, int> tree;
```

Comment: God damnit, I'll look into it.

Comment: namespace mctest2
{
    template <class T>
    struct Point3D
    {
    public:
        T x, y, z;

        Point3D(T _x, T _y, T _z) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z)
        {
        }
    };
}

Comment: namespace mctest2
{
    class ChunkTree
    {
    public:
        std::unordered_map<Point3D<int>, int> tree;

        ChunkTree();
        ~ChunkTree();
    };
}